# Collecting all identifers in scope

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I'm trying to collect all the identifiers that exist in scope by using an implicit macro, but I can't find an elegant way to find them.

```
val endPos = c.enclosingPosition.endOrPoint
val mNames = c.enclosingMethod
             .collect {case v: ValDef => v}
                 .filter(_.pos.start > endPos)
                 .map {case ValDef(_, name, _, _) => Ident(name)}
val cNames = c.enclosingClass
             .collect {case ValDef(_, name, _, _) => Ident(name)}
val names = mNames ++ cNames
```

The previous captures all variables, even if they are defined in different methods, but I need a way to filter the ValDefs that occur in methods from `cNames`. Calling `children` seemed like it might have worked, but I still get the ValDefs from inside other blocks.

My final goal is to be able to do `Logger.trace()` and have all the variables in scope logged. So

```
def test() = {
  val v = 2
  val z = "fdsaf"
  Logger.trace()
}
```

would log `v: 2, z: "fdsaf"`

**Edit 2:**

```
import c.universe._
val callingPos = c.enclosingPosition
val encMet = Option(c.enclosingMethod)

val classElements = c.enclosingClass
                    .asInstanceOf[ImplDefApi]
                    .impl.children
                    .collect {
    case v: Block => v.asInstanceOf[Tree]
    case v: DefDef => v.asInstanceOf[Tree]
    case v: ValDef => v.asInstanceOf[Tree]
    case v: ModuleDef => v.asInstanceOf[Tree]
}

val classFields = classElements.collect {case v@ValDef(_, name, _, _) if !v.isEmpty => Ident(name)}
val blockFields = classElements.collectFirst{
    case Block(body, ret) if positionIsInList(c)(body) => body.collect {
        case v@ValDef(_, name, _, _) if v.pos precedes callingPos => Ident(name)
    }
}.getOrElse(List())
val methodFields = encMet
                   .map(_.collect {case v@ValDef(_, name, _, _) if v.pos precedes callingPos => Ident(name)})
                   .getOrElse(List())

val names = classFields ++ blockFields ++ methodFields
```

Works in most cases, but fails on blocks.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately this use case is not something that is supported by Scala macros at the moment. Sure, something more or less working can be whipped up as you've demonstrated (thanks a lot for the examples by the way!), but to the best of my knowledge there's no robust way of achieving your goal.

In the future we might be able to tackle this challenge, but currently there are technical limitations that prevent us from exposing this kind of an API at the moment. Even casting to compiler internals, which sometimes helps in tricky cases, isn't going to help here. Actually, this is exactly the reason why in Scala 2.11 we have deprecated c.enclosingTree-style APIs: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/nf_ooEBn6-k.

If you could elaborate on what you're trying to achieve, I would be glad to help with looking into workarounds that might end up being useful to your use case.

Comment: I've edited my question to address my final goal, right before 'Edit 2:'. I've seen your pull request for enclosingOwner which looks like it would almost solve this, but I can't figure out how to get a `Tree` out of a `Symbol`.

Comment: Getting a tree out of a symbol is impossible, because symbols are just entries in the table of definitions available to the compiler without any AST information attached to them. This might change in the future, but so far it's not supported.

Comment: I don't think that it's possible to write this kind of macro at the moment. The closest you can get to looking up things in scope is with c.inferImplicitValue, but for that you need your thing to be implicit and of certain type known in advance.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep trying to hack around this, but manually writing the log statements isn't that much work.